# Codeception - How to test manipulated select box option values?

Tags: html, functional-testing, codeception

I want to force codeception to select a non-existing option in a html select box:

```
$I->selectOption('#foobar', 100000);
```

Once I hit the test, following message gets returned:

```
Input "foobarId" cannot take "100000" as a value (possible values: 0, 1, 2).
```

I want to check if there are errors shown after submitting the form. I got asked to write tests for manipulated option values.

Is there any work-around to achieve this?

Comment: If I use nice-select, how I can choose?

Answer (score 0):

I think that they are asking you to test what happens when the user clicks the various options, not submit an invalid option. I don't think most browsers will allow you to submit an invalid check box. Anyway, that would seem to just be a form validation, nothing to do with "manipulating" the values.

What happens when the user doesn't click anything?
What happens when the user clicks option1, then clicks option2, then submit?
What happens when the user clicks all three options? 
etc.